# Jetpack Compose Adding animation to horizontal Arrangement when switching from wrapContent to fillMax (expand and collapse)

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have to expand and collapse a Row container with horizontalArrangement as SpaceBetween.
It should be arranged in the sameway in expanded and collapsed state.
Also I want a slow animation from expand to collapse and collapse to expand.
If there are 2 Text inside the Row, while expanding one Text should move to left along with the expand and the other Text should move right along with the expand.

I tried 2 approaches, in one approach the arrangement is working but there is no animation while expanding. and the other the animation is working arrangement is not working.

```
  AnimationPOCsTheme {
                var isExpanded by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .clickable {
                            isExpanded = !isExpanded
                        }, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing))
                            .let { if (isExpanded) it.fillMaxSize() else it.wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.Center) }
                            .background(Color.Green),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Click")
                        Text(text = "Click2")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Approach 2:
Here animation is perfect but arrangement is not exactly what is required, it should move along with the animation:

```
  AnimationPOCsTheme {
                var isExpanded by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .clickable {
                            isExpanded = !isExpanded
                        }, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .wrapContentSize()
                            .background(Color.Red)

                    ) {
                        Row(
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .expandCollapse(isExpanded)
                                .background(Color.Green)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Click")
                            Text(text = "Click2")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```